# HttpWebRequest/Response issue

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I have an application running on iis(7) ( asp.net mvc if that matters ) and i want to connect to it ( a method from a controller obviously ) from a PDA.
I am using HttpWebRequest/Response but i get `"Unable to connect to the remote server" "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"`
If i am doing the same thing from a console application ( this time the client and server are the same machine ) it works fine
How to solve it ? Thanks.

Later edit: Problem solved. I just pulled out the mobile from the cradle and put it in again, it connected again to the pc and now it works

Comment: That's server/network related issue. Try on http://serverfault.com as your problem is not programming related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IS port 80 open for inbound requests? You may need to add a rule :

Windows Firewall with Advanced Security / Inbound Rules / New Rule / Port Rule

Answer (score 0):

Try it from a console application *not* running on the same machine. It may well be a firewall issue or something similar.

Alternatively, don't use a console app at all - just fire up a browser and hit any URL which will respond - even if it will respond with an error. That will at least show whether you can reach the server or not.

Comment: @gigi: You don't have *any* other machines you can test this from? Can you borrow a laptop from a friend or colleague?

Comment: if i user my browser, on the server machine, http://localhost... i can reach it of course

Comment: well i will be able to do it the next days but i was thinking you guys can help me solve it now :)